# Free scale in faceted polar plots not available anymore for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, polar-coordinates

For some time I used (and loved) the ability of **ggplot2** to create faceted plots on polar plots. In this case I plotted wind roses faceted by wind velocity or other wind attributes.

```
p <- ggplot(wind.data, aes(x=direction)) + geom_density(adjust=1)
p <- p + coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1)
p <- p + facet_wrap( ~ velocity.range, ncol= 3, scales = "free")
```

The scale free feature of facet_wrap was required because the resulting faceted distributions differ by orders of magnitude. However, since ggplot2 0.9.3.1 I get the following error:

```
Error en facet_render.wrap(plot$facet, panel, plot$coordinates, plot_theme(plot),  : 
  ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.
```

Why was this useful feature removed from newer ggplot versions? Any alternatives? I could create the plots in a loop and then put them all in a grid, but that's a step back from the clean faceted version.

Tnks!

Comment: From the [NEWS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/NEWS): "Previously when free scales were used with non-cartesian coords, they just wouldn't work. Now ggplot throws an error with an informative message."

Comment: Well, they did work for me :-) Maybe they did not under some circumstances.